# Apply autofilter on column using arrays value

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I am retrieving all values of a specific column and storing all the values in an array so that i can use these values to apply autofilter.

```
rowcount=objExcel.Activeworkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.count

Dim a()
Redim Preserve a(rowcount)
'msgbox rowcount

'Storing all column values in an array'

for i=2 to rowcount
  a(i-2) = objSrcWorksheet.Cells(i,7).Value
Next

'Checking values of array'
for i=2 to rowcount
  msgbox a(i-2)

'Applying Autofilter'
 With objSrcWorksheet


.Range("G1").AutoFilter 2,"=a(i-2)"  'Problem is here'
'.Range("G1").AutoFilter 2,"=2"     'While hardcoded values are working'

 End With
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript doesn't resolve variables inside strings. When you put `a(i-2)` in double quotes it becomes a literal string `"a(i-2)"` instead of the value of field `i-2` of array `a`.

Change `.AutoFilter 2, "=a(i-2)"` into `.AutoFilter 2, "=" & a(i-2)` and the problem will disappear.

Comment: I have one more query, is there any way so that i can apply autofilter only on the unique column values?

Comment: I'm not aware of any direct way to have AutoFilter select only unique values. However, you could add another column with a formula `=COUNTIF(B:B,INDIRECT("B"&ROW()))` and then set a filter for all rows where the value of that column is 1.